# Entity framework: Manually maintained mappings

Tags: entity-framework, ef-model-first

I've been using EF for a while (4 with model first) and so far I've not created any mapping manually. Whenever I need more entities/tables, I add an entity and the associations (all foreign key) and click "update database from model", which, as is well known, doesn't update any database from the model (although it does need a database connection for reasons I don't know). What it does is generating a storage model and the appropriate mappings to it, which are all stored back to the same edmx xml file.

So far, that has always been enough for me but I'm wondering what the workflow would be if one is to tweak the mappings and storage model manually. "Update database from model" overwrites all manual customization - so how is one to fix *most* of the mappings and storage model? Because I clearly don't want to do it all by hand - in fact I couldn't even figure out how to actually create a table in the storage model other than by editing the edmx in the xml.

Comment: Are you looking for [EF Migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx)?

Comment: @BradChristie No, the actual database management I do separately with a database project, and I'm very happy with that. I was only talking about what EF calls the storage model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. I just use a mixture of methods. If I add a field to the database, I just add the field to the model file. If I do a major restructure, I delete the table and recreate it by generating it from the database. Sometimes, I actually edit the edmx as XML to change or add things. You just kinda gotta figure out what process works best for you. I have managed to avoid heavy customization in the edmx by using the T4 template or changing the database and regenerating.

Comment: Thanks for that. Accepting your answer as long as no-one proves that there is a better way.